# IO Fortran format command issue

Tags: io, fortran, format

suppose we want to write the output of a n=16 element array of integers numbers `A(n)`:

```
write(*,1) (A(k), k=1,n)
1 format(16(I2,2x))
```

we cannot write `1 format(n(I2,2x))`

is there a way to overcome this problem? or do we need to change by hand the `format` command every time we change `n`?

Comment: Just use `*` instead of `n`, we have plenty of duplicates.

Comment: Else, do not use the `format` statement, use a format string. That is a normal string and you can edit it as you wish.

Comment: If you move to using `*` you are likely to have to do other things on top of changing the format to make this more general, but these are covered in the linked question. If you have difficulty implementing the changes do [edit] your question.